# undefined local variable or method `has_no_table'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, google-drive-api

Here's my 'note' model:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_no_table
    column :title, :string
    column :contents, :string
    def update_spreadsheet
        connection = GoogleDrive.login(ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"], ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"])
        ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('central-app-notes')
        if ss.nil?
        ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('central-app-notes')
        end
        ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row, 1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row, 2] = self.title
    ws[last_row, 3] = self.content
    ws.save
    end
end
```

I also added the "google_drive" gem.

However, when I try to access the page with the form, I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `has_no_table'
```

I'm not sure what's going on and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the method `has_no_table` comes from the activerecord-tableless gem

So include in your Gemfile

```
gem "activerecord-tableless", "~> 1.0"
```

Bundle and restart your server and hopefully that helps

Also check out the [activerecord-tableless gem](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless) for more information